# Service Fabric deployment in the cloud

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

We are switching to an actor based architecture for a subsystem in our product (We use C#), and we are considering either Akka.NET or Service Fabric actors. We have experience with Akka and Akka Clusters (in Scala), but the Service Fabric actors suits our purpose perfectly. It is, however, really difficult to find any material about deployment.

Is it possible at all to deploy on Azure at the moment (or can you join any preview programmes)? I can't find any indications of when a preview will be available, if it is not possible already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure deployment is not available yet. It will be launched as a preview later this year.

**Update**: Service Fabric is now available in public preview.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than later this year, weeks or months away?

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a timeframe as well.

Comment: It will be towards the end of the year, so months rather than weeks.

Comment: We are running out of months... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Update: Microsoft [now provides Service Fabric Continuous Integration documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/)

I have continuous delivery running w/the development SDK (all nodes on one VM) like this:

1. push to github.com
2. github.com tells Visual Studio Online to trigger a build.
3. A custom build definition with a custom ‪#PowerShell‬ script step who 7z’s the build artifacts and curl’s the file to the Windows Server 2012 R2 Azure VM instance
4. IIS is loaded on the VM to host basic auth over TLS, & the WebDav module simply for this upload (easier to configure than FTP or WebRM on Azure, for sure)
5. I wrote custom open-source code who monitors for a trigger file (https://github.com/corlib/trigger) and invokes a command, configured to invoke a custom deployment script. (very early, but functional for this purpose)
6. The deployment script decompresses the archive, loads the ServiceFabric application manifest to obtain the application type version. This version is used to deploy the application package to a unique location in the cluster, register it, and then start a monitored application upgrade (w/rollback to previous version on failure)